# Adding Toggle to list SwiftUI and saving toggle state while user is signed in

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to add a toggle to a list view to turn location on or off. I would also like to know how to keep the toggle state until the user signs out. Thank you to anyone who can help me with this. I don't want to add any location feature to it yet I'm just wanting to have the placeholder ready.

Here's my code;

```
import SwiftUI

    struct SettingsView: View {

@State private var notificationToggle : Bool = false
@State private var locationToggle : Bool = false
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

var body: some View {

    List{

        Section {

                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsAccountView()) {

                    Button(action: {
                        print("Account Settings")
                    }) {
                        SettingsCell(title: "Account", imgName: "person.crop.circle", clr: Color("Freshness"))
                    }

                }

                Toggle(isOn: $locationToggle {
                    print("locationToggled")
            }) {
                       SettingsCell(title: "Location", imgName: "location", clr: Color("Freshness"))
                    }

                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsNotificationsView()) {

                    Button(action: {
                        print("Notification Settings")
                    }) {
                        SettingsCell(title: "Notifications", imgName: "bell", clr: Color("Freshness"))
                    }
                }
        }

        Section {

                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsAboutView()) {

                    Button(action: {
                        print("About")
                    }) {
                        SettingsCell(title: "About", imgName: "info.circle.fill", clr: Color("ShipsOfficer").opacity(0.3))
                    }
                }
        }

    }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
    .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can always save local data with `UserDefaults` as such:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set("On", forKey: "toggleStatus")
```

and once the user logs out you can just:

```
defaults.removeObjectForKey("toggleStatus")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to save the toggle state on toggling and retrieve it when the `View` appears just add an `onTap` gesture to store and `onAppear` action block to retrieve the toggle state from `UserDefaults`. Here's how you achieve this:

```
Toggle(isOn: $locationToggle) {
    SettingsCell(title: "Location", imgName: "location", clr: Color("Freshness"))
}
.onTapGesture {
    print("locationToggle: \(self.locationToggle)")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.locationToggle, forKey: "locationToggle")
}
.onAppear {
    self.locationToggle = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "locationToggle")
}
```